# psql: reset and recreate database in one line of code

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to drop and recreate a postgresql database using one line of code like the following:

```
psql -h server_name -U webapp -f mydb_dump.sql database_name
```

but I get the following errors:

```
ERROR:  constraint "work_packets" for relation "work_packets_workpacket" already exists
WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"
```

What am I missing and how can I also pass the password to avoid a prompt?

Thank you

Comment: What statements you have in `mydb_dump.sql`?

Comment: If `database_name` is the database you are trying to `DROP` that will not work as you cannot drop the database you are connected to. Also if others are connected to it(though in PG 13 you can use `FORCE` in that case).